# How omit text between and including matching characters?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

If I have a text containing markdown matching markings e.g.

"Strikethrough uses two tildes. ~~Scratch this.~~"

What would be a good way to delete all those occurrences such as - in this example - 
"~~Scratch this.~~"?

Comment: Do you want to delete the characters between the characters? Or do you just want to delete the characters and not the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to search all strike-through text and delete it. That can be done with the following substitute command:

```
:%s/\~\~\_.\{-}\~\~//g
```

- The escaped tilde `\~` is needed as `~` "matches the last given substitute string" (`:help /~`)
- The `\_.` matches any character *including* newline, so multi-line strike-through is handled. (`:help /\_.` and `:help /\_`)
- The `\{-}` matches "as few as possible". (`help /\{-`) BTW: Using `*` here would match from the first to the last `~~` in the file, as `*` matches "as many as possible".

This command also handles multiple strike-throughs per line.

Answer (score 2):

Put these in your `vimrc` and then source the `vimrc` with `:source $MYIMRC`:

```
" simple text-objects
for s:char in [ '~', '_', '.', ':', ',', ';', '<Bar>', '/', '<Bslash>', '*', '+', '%', '`' ]
    execute 'xnoremap i' . s:char . ' :<C-u>normal! T' . s:char . 'vt' . s:char . '<CR>'
    execute 'onoremap i' . s:char . ' :normal vi' . s:char . '<CR>'
    execute 'xnoremap a' . s:char . ' :<C-u>normal! F' . s:char . 'vf' . s:char . '<CR>'
    execute 'onoremap a' . s:char . ' :normal va' . s:char . '<CR>'
endfor
```

Then you can do `di{char}` to delete the texts in between the `{char}` and `da{char}` to delete the texts in between the `{char}` along with the characters themselves.

The for loop iterates over `:h list` containing the `{char}` and execute `:h mapping` commands for `:h operator-pending-mode` and `:h visual-mode` so that the `{char}` in the list can act as `:h text-objects`